# changes to text file in eclipse not reflected on jsp page unless rerun

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp

I have links pointing to text files in my eclipse project. I am changing their contents using javascript. The change is reflected in the actual file. But the link still loads the older file contents. I tried giving no cache in jsp as well as html meta tag. I even added a random variable to page name each time a page reloads... but still the changes are not visible until and unless i rerun the page from eclipse... Even if i manually delete the file contents, the changes are still not visible...

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If Eclipse has to deploy those files, as in you're not serving them from where they are in the workspace, it needs to know that they've changed to redeploy them.

Comment: No the thing is that if I am creating a new text file, then they are shown on the UI. However when I am modifying an existing text file, the changes are not reflected...(Both the operations are done through UI)

Comment: Do you have automatic builds enabled?